# How to Populate lookup field values between case and custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, lookup

[image]I have Standard Object: Case, which has look up field VIN__c(Field) with Custom Object VEH_Veh__c.
My aim is when i select Vin number(VIN__C) from case, such that model,brand from VEH_Veh__c should be displayed according to the vin number selected in Lookup .

I used the following code.Its showing error....

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class RelatedController 
{
    // Defining objects
    public Case selectedCase { get; set; }
    public VEH_Veh__c selectedveh { get; set; }
    // Constructor where the user data will be pre-populated
    public RelatedController ()
    {
        selectedCase = new Case();
    }

    // Method for reading selected user data
    public pageReference readUser()
    {
        selectedveh = [ Select Id,Brand__C,Model__C from VEH_Veh__c Where Id = :selectedCase.VIN__c ];
        System.debug('selectedveh----------------------->>'+selectedveh );
        return null;
    } 
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;

    public RelatedController(ApexPages.StandardController std)
    {
        stdCtrl=std;
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case"  extensions="RelatedController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Create/Edit">

      <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="accinfo" title="Account Information">
          <apex:inputField value="{!selectedCase .VIN__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!readUser}" />
          </apex:inputField>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Case.VehicleBrand__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Case.Model__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:actionRegion>

      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>

     </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please help how to display brand,model in vf page for the particular vin number selected in lookup.

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` you are not rerendering the section. Put the section you want to be updated on selection inside an `outputpanel`, give it an `id` and give this id in the `rerender` attribute of `actionsupport`.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!selectedCase .VIN__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!readUser}" rerender="section"/>
</apex:inputField>

<apex:outputPanel id="section">
   <apex:outputField value="{!Case.VehicleBrand__c}"/>
   <apex:outputField value="{!Case.Model__c}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Its not working. Error in controller attempt to "de reference null object"

Comment: You need to give more information, on where exactly it is giving the error.